# Yii2 validateCsrfToken does not work as expected

Tags: ajax, yii2, csrf-protection

I have the following create action that has two ways to be accessed, one via AJAX and the other ordinary way:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->validateCsrfToken(Yii::$app->request->post('csrf', 'falsesds'))){

          \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
      return [
          'search' => Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken(),
          'code' => 100,
      ];
    }
        $model = new Statics();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure that there is no any parameter sent to the action named `csrf` with the value of csrf token generated in the source page. inspite of the described, the AJAX request always run perfectly, i.e there is a JSON response with the `search` key. The following is the Jquery AJAX code that I have used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
  $(".addContent").click(function(event){   
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(this.href,{
      data:{
        'path': getParameterByName('path', this.href),
        'position': getParameterByName('position', this.href)
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        alert(data.search+"\n\n"+csrfToken);
      },
      error: function(data){
        alert('bad');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I want to secure this process and I don't know how to use Yii2 CSRF token to do that. In other words, I want to prevent any [client-side](/questions/tagged/client-side) modification to the posted parameters, i.e `path` and `position`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually *csrf token* has nothing to do with submitted data correctness, which you want to achieve, as I can understand from your question. It only can guarantee that the data is submitted from safe place and can be processed. Consider using some type of *hash* to check that there is no modification in posted parameters.